# How can I pivot column values into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to pivot one column's values into multiple columns. This is a sample from the AX table below:

```
AAAREFNUMVALUE  AAATRANSPORTTABLE   AAAREFNUMTYPE
5000130742      5637146247              2
01832007        5637146247              3
14252108        5637146247              1
NS              5637146247              8
5000131013      5637146248              2
01829347        5637146248              3
11910275        5637146248              1
NS              5637146248              8
```

Below is the end result as an excel report that I need using SQL. It has all related fields on the same row. The AAATRANSPORTTABLE field relates the values and the AAAREFNUMTYPE is how I would like the new columns to be arranged:

```
Alpha Pro Number     Shippers BL #          PO Number     Shippers Number
11910275          SA03261264             01829347        NS
14252108          SA03256804             01832007        NS
```

I have tried to use multiple SELECT statements to just filter the data down however I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I have considered the PIVOT and MERGE functions though I am having difficulty visualizing how to solve this problem. The data I have provided is a simplified version of the problem, but any direction would be very appreciated.

```
SELECT    AAAREFNUMVALUE AS 'Alpha Pro Number',
          AAATRANSPORTTABLE AS 'Table ID',
          AAAREFNUMTYPE AS 'Number Type',
          (SELECT AAAREFNUMTYPE 
          FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS 
          WHERE AAAREFNUMTYPE = 2) AS 'Shippers BL#'
FROM          dbo.AAATOREFNUMS
WHERE        (AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery, but it needs to be correlated:

```
SELECT a.AAAREFNUMVALUE AS "Alpha Pro Number",
       a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE AS "Table ID",
       a.AAAREFNUMTYPE AS "Number Type",
       (SELECT a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE 
        FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
        WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
             a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 2
       ) AS "Shippers BL#"
FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a
WHERE AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1 ;
```

I strongly discourage you from using single quotes to quote identifiers.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.  I changed them to double quotes which work in most databases.

Comment: Gordon, this query now completes, but with the same error mentioned above. I am assuming I have incomplete data somewhere I just can't verify.  AAAREFNUMVALUE does contain duplicates. The same error occurs after I insert the DISTINCT command into both SELECT statements. Also, I don't think I clarified well, but I need 'SELECT a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE' instead of 'SELECT a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE' in the subquery. Any thoughts? Thanks so much!